# Help me resolve compiletime error?

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

When I execute my code I get this error:

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Id].contains(String) at line 29 column 12

Here is my code:

```
List<Case> cas = Trigger.new;

List<Integration__c> listAll = [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,account__c,integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c ];

for(Case c : cas  )
{
    for(Integration__c intObj:listAll)
    {
        //this line causing for compiletime error
        if(intObj.IntegrationAccount__c.contains(c.Account.Name)){
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

What this means is that `IntegrationAccount__c` is a lookup field, and the value thus contains an Id. If you are expecting the name, you could instead query `IntegrationAccount__r.Name`. Note that this value can be null, and calling `contains` on a null variable would cause the runtime to de-reference a null variable, leading to a `NullPointerException`. Never assume a variable (including any field value) is not null unless you can be absolutely certain.

Instead of:

```
if (intObj.IntegrationAccount__c.contains(c.Account.Name))
```

Use:

```
String accountName = intObj.IntegrationAccount__r.Name;
if (accountName != null && contains(c.Account.Name))
```

Note that you have to add `IntegrationAccount__r.Name` to your query or you will get a different exception. Your code has some other serious problems with it (for instance you should only query `Integration__c` records which might actually match), but this should at least get you started.

Comment: i updated as you said with relationship field it's working but 
 
i got this Exception when creating a case abobe details page it shows : Apex trigger Type caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Type: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Integration__c.IntegrationAccount__r: Trigger.Type: line 30, column 1 for that add "cIds" object at the end of query again i get this exception System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0